# vim error `.git/hooks/post-commit.sample/post-commit" E212: Can't open file for writing`

Tags: git, vim, githooks, post-commit-hook

In the `.git/hooks` folder I need to make a `post-commit.sample` folder and add a `post-commit` file to it (and edit a line into it). There was no `post-commit` file or `post-commit.sample` folder so I used mkdir and touch to create the file.
But when I edited the post-commit file with `vim .git/hooks/post-commit.sample/post-commit`it gives me the following error

`.git/hooks/post-commit.sample/post-commit" E212: Can't open file for writing`

ls -l gives me this

```
ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 shrey shrey 0 Feb 23 20:43 post-commit
```

If you could please help me. (I am a newbie ofcourse)

Comment: I guess you shouldn't have a `.git/hooks/post-commit.sample/post-commit`, you should have a `.git/hooks/post-commit instead`.

Comment: How do I do that? What command should I use to edit post-commit and make the error go?

Comment: [git client side hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)